# Jakarta EE compatible application servers versions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, application-server

I see here https://jakarta.ee/compatibility/ the list with all compatible application servers for each JEE version.
The question is, are they the minimum compatible versions or do I have to use the exact same version as written in there?

For example, one of written compatible application servers for Jakarta EE 8 is Wildfly 18.0.0. Would it still be compatible with the latest Wildfly (25.0.1) as of today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is, are they the minimum compatible versions or do i have to use the exact same version as written in there?

They are minimum compatible versions, but there are also *maximum* compatible versions existing for older specs, and that isn't told by the page explicitly. For example Wildfly 23+ (current known versions) are Jakarta EE 9 compatible. Wildfly 18 and above but below 23 are Jakarta EE 8/Java EE 8 compatible.

See [source about Jakarta EE 9](https://dev.to/theelitegentleman/introducing-jakarta-ee-9-1hj8):

> **No backward compatibility.** Jakarta EE 9 is not backward compatible with Jakarta EE 8 or Java EE 8. It's not recommended to mix Jakarta EE 8 artifacts with Jakarta EE 9 and vice versa.

Since Jakarta EE 9 changed namespaces from Java EE 8/Jakarta EE 8, it is not possible to be compatible with both even in theory.